# Android equivalent to Remote Messages/WiFiSMS on iOS?

Tags: sms, mms

One of my favorite things about my iPhone was the ability to receive/send SMS/MMS through my web browser on my computer. As far as I know, Android has alternatives for this, but they all rely on an online service which isn't ideal.

Is there any way to send/receive SMS/MMS through a PC without the use of an online service?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) which offers more functionalities.
*It does not need internet service*

> ✔ SMS: Send and receive individual or group messages.
>   ✔ Files: Transfer files between Android and computer from any network. Share files and chat with friends.
>   ✔ Notification Mirror: Mirror phone notifications from any allowed apps to computer.
>   - Contacts: View and edit all the contacts.
>   - Photos: Transfer photos between Android and computer.
>   - Music & Videos: Play and manage music & videos on Android and transfer them between Android and computer.
>   - Ringtones: Set music as ringtone and export ringtones.
>   - Screenshot: View the real time screen of Android devices, take static screenshots. (requires root)
>   - Apps: Import and export .apk files.
>   - Camera: See through the lens of both front and back cameras.
>   - URL: Push url to Android and open it with default web browser.
>   - Clipboard: Share clipboard content between Android and computer.

Alterntively, [Wifi SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.giox.wifisms&hl=en) for android offers to send/recieve SMS